# How to scale Graphs and Vector field on the same plot nicely? [weird scales ]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to matplotlib and trying to plot 2 graphs and one vector field on them on the same plot.

When I run the code below, I ran into some scaling problems. I asssume it's due to the undefined y axis on the graphs but I couldn't figure out how to plot them with y. When I define y's interval, I got very weird pics. I need some high resolution pics [0,7],[0,7] for the graphs and vector fields. When I ran the code below, I got results from the negative y axis which I don't want to plot.

I also wonder how I can make this plot bigger and higher resolution. The current image's size is pretty small.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

#graphs
a=1
b=1
x= np.mgrid[0:6:15j]   #problematic part I assume
k = b/(a*x)
l = (-1 + (b+1)*x) / (a*(x**2))

ca =plt.plot(x, k, x,l)
#Vector Field,Quiver 
Y, X = np.mgrid[0:6:12j, 0:6:12j]

U = 1- (b + 1)* X + ( a*(X**2) * Y)
V = (b * X) - (a * X**2 * Y)

speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
UN = U/speed
VN = V/speed

quiv = plt.quiver(X, Y, UN, VN, 
           color='Black', 
           headlength=5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

When i run your code, I get runtime warnings for division by zero, which turns the first value of k infinite, and l -infinite. not sure that's your problem though, what exactly do you mean by scaling problems? do you want the graph to be focused on a specific range of x and y? you would normally use [plt.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [plt.ylim](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) for that sort of thing. try adding something like this:

```
plt.ylim((-0.2,6.2))
```

if you're running this from the command line, you should also be able to resize the graph manually (just by dragging the corner of the window), and save that graph, for a larger image. if you need an even higher resolution or more precise control, check out the [savefig](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) function. you can call it before running show().

Comment: Oh I got it! I added the x.lim and y.lim and set the fig size right after importing and it worked.thank you!